# Running Hadoop Jar in Ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, hadoop, jar

I am trying to run a jar file in Hadoop. I have converted jar file using Eclipse export function. Now the problem is when I run jar file it says classnotfoundexception. My main class in the subfolder e.g. WordCount->count->src->countFunction->wordCount. Can someone tell me how to give path correctly in this case. I am using this command ./bin/hadoop jar /usr/local/WordCount.jar wordCount /usr/local/hadoop/examples/input /usr/local/hadoop/examples/input. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$ bin/hadoop jar /usr/local/wordcount.jar org.myorg.WordCount /usr/local/wordcount/input /usr/local/wordcount/output
```

Comment: This is working. i have written my own code. Do I need to set classpath of the jar files to the path in hadoop e.g. right now it is set to something C:\\\. Should this be replaced with /usr/local/hadoop?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set job.setJarByClassName(DriverClassName.class) in your driver class main method? I had the same issue in past and resolved after setting it.